# Open jqueryUI modal with a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I cant figure this out for the life of me. I want to open a modal (dialoge) box with jqueryUI. All the examples use a button to do it.

Can someone post an example which uses a simple link to open a basic jqueryui diagloge box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this sample that I made on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qWNa9/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind the dialog opening event to someone clicking on the link, you could use something like this:

```
$("#linkid").on("click", function() {
    $("#dialogId").dialog();
});
```

linkid == the ID on your  tag, and dialogId == the ID on the containing element of what you want displayed in your dialog

Comment: try this one, didn't look up the CSS files to get the dialog's to show up like the jqueryui site, but it functions :) -- http://jsfiddle.net/NMWMR/10/

Answer (score 0):

just use the dialog("open") function.

```
$(".alink").dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
```

Then bind to the .click() event

Answer (score 0):

Following will help you, adjust according to your scenario

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/